# Python 3 order of testing undetermined

Tags: python, comparison, python-3.x, boolean

```
string='a'
p=0
while (p <len(string)) & (string[p]!='c') :
                    p +=1

print ('the end but the  process  already died ')
       while (p <1) & (string[p]!='c') :
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I want to test a condition up to the  end of a string (example string length=1)
why are  both parts  of the and  executed  is the condition is already false!
 as long as  `p < len(string)`. the second part does not even need executing.
 if it does a lot of performance can be lost

Comment: Why are you using the bit-wise `&` operator?

Comment: Not that's some wheel-reinventing code. How about `p = string.find(c)` (returns -1 instead of `len(string)-1` if it's not there - so it's even better, as in, not ambiguous)?

Answer (score 9):

You're not using proper boolean `and`. Use it and you won't see this problem. What you're using (`&`) is a bitwise comparison, which evaluates both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise AND, "a & b", should be thought of as

```
function _bitwise_and(A,B):
    # A and B are Python expressions
    #   which result in lists of 1's and 0's

    a = A.evaluate()
    b = B.evaluate()

    return [ 1 if abit==1 and bbit==1 else 0 for abit,bbit in zip(a,b)]
```

so, graphically,

```
a:   ...  0 1 1 0
b:   ...  1 0 1 0
         --------
a&b  ...  0 0 1 0   <- each bit is 1 if-and-only-if the
                       corresponding input bits are both 1
```

and the result is a list of bits, packed into an integer.

.

Logical AND, "a and b", should instead be thought of as

```
function _and(A,B):
    # A and B are Python expressions which result in values having truthiness

    a = A.evaluate()
    if is_truthy(a):
        b = B.evaluate()
        return b
    else:
        return a
```

.

Notice: if the result of A is falsy, B never gets evaluated - so if expression B has an error when evaluated, **bitwise AND will result in an error** while **logical AND will not**.

This is the basis for the common Python idiom,

```
while (offset in data) and test(data[offset]):
    do_something_to(data[offset])
    next offset
```

... because data[offset] is only evaluated if offset is a useable (non-error-producing) value.

By using '&' instead of 'and', you guarantee an error by evaluating data[last_offset+1] at the end of your loop.

.

Of course, this could have been avoided with another common idiom:

```
for ch in string if ch=='c':
    do_something_to(ch)
```

which avoids IndexError problems altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [boolean operators](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) and and or rather than the bitwise operators & and |